# limit Journey Builder APIs when using a corporate edition

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, journeybuilder

if I develop a Journey builder having a API event entry source,
shall I consider the API limits for my Marketing Cloud license?

For instance, according to this [official sheet](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/mc_email_journey_pricing_sheet.pdf), having a Corporate license, API Calls are 6 M per year. Are those 6M counted also for such JB (API event entry source)?
If yes, What happens after I reach this 6 M limit?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, yes. These API calls will count towards the quota.

If you breach the API call limit, everything should continue to work - but, depending on the number, you could get a call from your MC Account Executive asking to purchase additional API calls package.

Although it is possible these limits are not yet enforced. So you might get away even if you exceed it for now, but ***do try*** to consider these limits in mind.

That being said, there is still no way to see your current quota of used / available API calls in the system. This is something only MC support or AE would be able to provide if needed.